# RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x11b3df048>

Tags: python, tornado

When I asked for the API with Postman, I got the error.
The error is `"RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x11b3df048>"`

The code (python3.7 tornado)

```py
async def post_data(self, url, param_dict):
    """
    send post requests
    :param url:
    :param param_dict:
    :return:
    """
    post_data = self._gen_request_data(param_dict)
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}

    import tornado.httpclient
    request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(
        url, method="POST", headers=headers, body=post_data, validate_cert=False
    )

    response = await tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(request)
    return response.body
```

Full error output:

```
[E 190516 10:34:31 basehandler:205] HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='127.0.0.1:12601', method='POST', uri='/didiapp/ocr/submit?image=', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Postman-Token': '7dc560ec-bb6d-4378-95a7-60dfed96d07c', 'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.6.0', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:12601', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------875189288125929592701049', 'Content-Length': '47337', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'})
Task got bad yield: <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x11b3df048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.pyenv/versions/3.7.1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jplib3/basehandler.py", line 201, in process_module
    await method.__call__()
  File "/horus/service/thirdparty/pdd_express.py", line 79, in post_data
    response = await tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(request)
  File "<string>", line 3, in __await__
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x11b3df048>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this means that you're using an old version of Tornado in combination with something that's using asyncio, without installing the asyncio integration. Either upgrade to the latest version of tornado or add tornado.platform.install() to the start of your program.

Comment: I use your advice.This problem was solved by upgrading tornado to the latest version.Thank！

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from tornado.platform import asyncio
response = await asyncio.to_asyncio_future(tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(request))
```

instead:

```
response = await tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(request)
```